# Getting/creating ViewContainerRef without ViewChild query

Tags: angular

I'm creating a layout with D3, and I'm trying to dynamically insert Angular components into the structure.

I've managed to get components dynamically created using a ViewContainerRef injected into the parent component:

```
constructor(vcRef: ViewContainerRef...
```

I could also have got a ViewContainerRef from a html element in the template like this:

```
@ViewChild('htmlElementINeed', { read: ViewContainerRef }) targetConterinRef;
```

However, as I'm dynamically creating the html elements wher I need my components using D3, I cannot use the injected `ViewContainerRef`, or get a `ViewContainerRef` from the template using `@ViewChild`.

The angular documentation [lists these as the two ways to access it:](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ViewContainerRef-class.html):

> To access a ViewContainerRef of an Element, you can either place a Directive injected with ViewContainerRef on the Element, or you obtain it via a ViewChild query.

Is there any way to manually create a ViewContainerRef, or get one for an element not defined in the template? Is it a restriction of Angular that I can only dynamically create components on a html element that is already in template at compile time?

Comment: Only if you create and compile a component at runtime http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960. `ViewContainerRef` need to be known when a component is compiles. With AoT, this is when the application is built for deployment.

Comment: Any idea how to do it with JIT? I've found lots of examples of how to compile components that are dynamic - but that's not the issue, it's the *inserting* them dynamically where i have the problem.

Comment: I'd have to create a component with D3, parse it into Angular, to compile it into a component. I might try to see if I can *move* it within the DOM to where it needs to be.

Comment: You can create a component with the D3 markup statically added to a dynamically compiled component. There you can add template variables to the D3 elements and then query them using `@ViewChild('xxx')` to get `ViewContainerRef` where you can add components dynamically.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer what do you mean with template variables?

Comment: `<div #xxx></div>` allows you to query by string (as you do in your question. You need to create and compile a component at runtime if you need this in dynamically created HTML. Angular only processes anything Angular-related in HTML when a component is compiled.

Comment: @Joe If I understood correctly, I had more or less the same problem with tables. And for creating "dynamic viewContainerRef" my solution was create a dynamic component that has dynamic viewContainerRef. In your case your biggest Component should be created dynamically ( a plain string ) add the viewContainerRef and then when compiled yours ViewContainerRef will be dynamic.

Comment: @Joe also you can use now ngTemplateOutlet here is a
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564914/multiple-transclusion-using-ngfor-in-angular2