# Multiple transclusion using ngFor in Angular2

Tags: angular, ngfor, transclusion, angular2-ngcontent

I'm pretty new in angular2 and I'm trying to make a small angular component called "**grid**" that simply rearranges its content using transclusion.

Its template

## grid component template (grid.component.ts)

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-content select="[grid-item-index=0]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-content select="[grid-item-index=1]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-content select="[grid-item-index=2]"></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-content select="[grid-item-index=3]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-content select="[grid-item-index=4]"></ng-content>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-content select="[grid-item-index=5]"></ng-content>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is part of the parent component that uses it.

## parent template

```
<grid>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.grid-item-index]="i">
    <span>{{item}}</span>
  </div>
</grid>
```

Here's a [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/aUZx5VDwkYKqoldejHit/).

But the result displays no content. But using...

```
<grid>
  <div grid-item-index="0">item 0</div>
  <div grid-item-index="1">item 1</div>
  <div grid-item-index="2">item 2</div>
  <div grid-item-index="3">item 3</div>
  <div grid-item-index="4">item 4</div>
  <div grid-item-index="5">item 5</div>
</grid>
```

it works fine and the result was as I expected.

A [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/s4qU6luzFvj3p60WRsDl/) of this last working case.

Can achieve this result using a ngfor or similar.

I've tried using nth-child css pseudo class to avoid using the index but it doesn't work too.

### UPDATE

I've made some progress based on @yurzui (Thanks!!) answer. It allows to map content with an *grid-item-index* value to the view container with the same *grid-item-index* value.

#### parent.component.html

```
<grid>
    <ng-template *ngFor="let item of items; let i=index" 
    [grid-item-index]="(items.length-1)-i">
        <span >{{item}}</span>
    </ng-template> 
</grid>
```

#### grid-item-index directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[grid-item-index]'
})
export class GridItemIndexDirective {
  @Input('grid-item-index') index: any;

  constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef, public tRef: TemplateRef) {}
}
```

#### grid.component.ts

```
@ContentChildren(GridItemIndexDirective) sources: QueryList<GridItemIndexDirective>;
  @ViewChildren(GridItemIndexDirective) containers: QueryList<GridItemIndexDirective>;

  constructor(
    private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const len = this.sources.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      const destinationContainer = this.containers.find(x => x.index == i);
      const source = this.sources.find(x => x.index == i);
      if (destinationContainer) {
        destinationContainer.vcRef.createEmbeddedView(source.tRef);
        this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // this solves ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
      }
    }
  }
```

Check this [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/tEX9l0PS4aayDABXErnv/)

Comment: Is your data received asynchronously ?

Comment: No, it's an array defined in the parent component.

Comment: Could you provide a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co) of your problem ? It's difficult to see what could cause this behaviour.

Comment: Added a Plunker to the description. One for the not working case with ngFor and another for the working case without ngfor.

Comment: My guess is that the structure of your grid component is not being recognized by *ngFor, the component being static.

Comment: As I understand the grid component must transclude the result of ngFor. And this result is the same as the second case (the one without the ngFor). I don't know what's wrong and whether there is any alternative.

Comment: Option 1 https://plnkr.co/edit/5YZpGSwhC5epCv6gWhjZ?p=preview Since `template="` is deprecated then https://plnkr.co/edit/GzaFRu2T8vKqyPdEkBjv?p=preview

Comment: Option2 https://plnkr.co/edit/u2Jin4DA12t4LhtsRQv7?p=preview

Comment: @yurzui  That works pretty nicely!! Thanks a lot!. Can a selector be added to determine wich content is added to each ng-template?

Comment: By the way. If you post your solution as an anwser i can accept it

Comment: @Jman Which plunker did you mean when were asking about selector?

Comment: @yurzui I'm talking about [Option2](https://plnkr.co/edit/u2Jin4DA12t4LhtsRQv7?p=preview). I think is the best option. When i ask about a selector i mean add a selector that can be used to pick the exact content to add to any ng-template (like grid-item-index in the description). Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ngTemplateOutlet](https://plnkr.co/edit/GzaFRu2T8vKqyPdEkBjv?p=preview) to achieve this but there is another approach that uses low-level API:

**parent.component.html**

```
<grid>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <span>{{item}}</span>
  </div>
</grid>
```

Additional directive that will help us to recognize destination index.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[grid-item-index]'
})
export class GridItemIndexDirective {
  @Input('grid-item-index') index: any;

  constructor(public vcRef: ViewContainerRef) {}
}
```

**grid.component.html**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-template grid-item-index="1"></ng-template>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-template grid-item-index="2"></ng-template>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-template grid-item-index="3"></ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-template grid-item-index="4"></ng-template>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-template grid-item-index="5"></ng-template>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <ng-template grid-item-index="6"></ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**grid.component.ts**

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef, { read: ViewContainerRef }) vcRef: ViewContainerRef;
@ViewChildren(GridItemIndexDirective) containers: QueryList<GridItemIndexDirective>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  const len = this.vcRef.length;
  for( var i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
    const destinationContainer = this.containers.find(x => x.index == i);
    if(destinationContainer) {
      const view = this.vcRef.detach(0);
      destinationContainer.vcRef.insert(view);
    }
  }
}
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/RVIcSTeEIjTDoB6aGpD7?p=preview)**

Comment: Would it be possible to add the directive (item-grid-index) to the content in order to map its content to the same item-grid-index in the view? This way you can alter the order they will be added  and even discard content not having the directive.

Comment: Do you mean like in your origin question `<div *ngFor="let item of items; index as i" [attr.grid-item-index]="i">`?

Comment: You might also be interested in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44595942/how-to-use-a-child-template-inside-a-custom-table-component-to-display-each-row He is building table as well.

Comment: Here is my table example https://github.com/alexzuza/angular2-typescript-systemjs/tree/lection/src/table

Comment: Yes, that was what  i mean. Matching the content item with a grid-item-index value to the view item with the same grid-item-index value. I'll take a look to the question mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Then i think better way would be using ngTemplateOutlet

Comment: The downside is that you need always to use an array. With the other method the content can come from a ngFor or you can add it directly so is more flexible.

Comment: Anyway this last feature is a nice to have

Comment: This plunker should work for both cases https://plnkr.co/edit/OwTevzDOTBoW12EW67to?p=preview

Comment: The problem with that last one is that it ignores the grid-item-index when usign a ngFor. I've made some progress based on one of your proposals. I think it works pretty well (you can even reverse the items order). Check this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9BXspWxbQPN90Sk2q5p0?p=preview). Any improvement is welcome. Thanks